# Why does hjust move my labels up and down, and vjust left and right? Isn't that backward?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've created a chart in RStudio and this is part of my code:

```
theme(
    plot.title = element_text(colour = "#ec008c", family = "Inter", size = 25),
    axis.title.y = element_text(size = 14, family = "Inter", hjust = 0.1),
    axis.text.x = element_text(family = "Inter"),
    axis.text.y = element_text(family = "Inter"),
    plot.subtitle = element_text(family = "Inter")
  )
```

I understand that `hjust` (i.e. horizontal justification) and `vjust` (i.e. vertical justification) are used to move labels around, my question is why does this code using `hjust` move the y-axis title *up and down* rather than *left and right*?

It makes more sense to me intuitively to use `vjust` to move the axis title up and down, is there something wrong with my thought process?

Comment: it is justified (0 - down or left, 1 - up or right) relative to the axis, eg, if you were to rotate the figure such that the axis you are modifying is on top, it would look correct

Comment: Yeah I understand that the value that has to be used lies between 0 and 1. Not quire sure what you mean by rotating the figure so that the y-axis is on top, why do I have to do that when IMO it's just intuitive to use vjust to move the axis title up and down?

Comment: vjust _does_ move the title up and down _relative to the axis_

Comment: Ahh, right, I get you now. That does make more sense. As a newbie it just seems more intuitive to think of it as moving left and right along the x-axis (i.e. horizontally on the screen), but I guess it is better to make it relative to the axis itself. Just more confusing to understand at first. Thank you for the insight!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To expand a little bit on the discussion in the comments, the `hjust` parameter is not relative to the axis in theory (though in practise it is), but the `hjust` parameter is relative to the direction of the text. Perhaps a visual indicator makes it easier to grasp. In the example below we repeat `hjust = c(0, 0.5, 1)` for three angles of text, relative to the point that defines the text's `x` and `y`.

```r
df <- expand.grid("Test!", hjust = c(0, 0.5, 1), angle = c(0, 45, 90))

grid::grid.newpage()

grid::grid.points(
  x = seq(0.1, 0.9, length.out = nrow(df)),
  y = rep(0.5, nrow(df)),
  pch = 21,
  gp = grid::gpar(col = "red", fill = "red", fontsize = 10),
  default.units = "npc"
)

grid::grid.text(
  x = seq(0.1, 0.9, length.out = nrow(df)),
  df$Var1, hjust = df$hjust, vjust = 0.5, rot = df$angle
)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-02-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>